# Javascript or jQuery popup when user click links other than Submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have created a `form` where user can create his profile, now I want that if user do not `click` on ***save/submit*** button on the page and clicks on any other available link other than save.

Then he should get confirm popup of JavaScript mentioning that you are aborting the creation of profile. I am unable to find any event via which I can achieve this.

Other links are navigation links available on my page.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: that is called `unload` event.

Comment: @jai unload working perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using button for submit and others as a link then you can find out like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).('on','click',function(){
    var pressedButton = $(this).text();
    if(pressedButon == "Submit" || pressedButton =="Save")
      {
        return false;
      }
    else
      {
        $("a").on('click',function() {
          var confirmAns = confirm('Your message');
          if(confirmAns == true)
            {
              // DO whatever you want...
            }
          else
            {
              //Do whatever you want...
            }
        });
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **onblur** event for it and you can achieve your goal. So when a user click anywhere in your web page then the onblur event automatically fire.
You should use onblur event on your save/submit button.

```
<button onblur="myFunction()" type="button">Save</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var txt;
  var r = confirm("You are aborting the creation of profile");
  if (r == true) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using some plugin. There is one jQuery plugin ["Are You Sure"](https://github.com/codedance/jquery.AreYouSure)

So you just need below code snippet

```
$('form').areYouSure();
// OR
$('form.my_form_class').areYouSure();
```

There are some advanced option available with plugin. Checkout its documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you want this two possibilities:
    1.User clicks submit button: form gets submitted
    2.User clicks "a" link: get alert asking for confirmation to leave the registration process.

First point will be done automatically as it's a form submit button without the need of extra jQuery.

Second point would just need the following code in order to show the confirmation button:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click',function(e){
      if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to exit the registration process?")){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```